# WSH Jscript AppActivate() and Sleep()

Tags: jscript

I'm trying to learn JScript (not javascript) but I'm having a hell of a time finding resources. What I want to do is manipulate the windows shell to create a program that manipulates other programs so I specifically need to be able to use Jscript's AppActivate() function to switch focus between windows however it doesn't work. I'm assuming it doesn't work because the calls to AppActivate are happening before the windows I'm trying to manipulate fully load?

Could someone please:

Give me a working example of switching between say, calculator and notepad, also give me some good reference material?

Also, how do I pause the program at the end of execution so I can read the errors in the command prompt?

This is what I wrote, and it crashes every time.

```
    import System;
import System.Drawing;
import System.Windows.Forms;
import Accessibility;


//Open calculator, wait 3 seconds, open notepad, wait three seconds, change focus to calculator.
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("calc");
WshShell.Sleep(3000);
WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe");
WshShell.Sleep(3000);
AppActivate("calc");
```

Comment: Here are some more resources: http://www.limm.mgimo.ru/doc/jscript/htm/jstutor.htm, http://www.petergottlieb.com/docs/spect/DOASIS/jscript_tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The first lines of your script (import ...) aren't WSH JScript. Delete them. The WScript.Shell object doesn't have a .Sleep method. That method is provided by the (global) WScript object. To use .AppActivate, you need to specify the WScript.Shell object.

Working code:

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("calc");
WScript.Sleep(3000);
WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe");
WScript.Sleep(3000);
WshShell.AppActivate("calc");
```

To see what's going on, start your script from a console ('DOS box').

Start reading [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

**Update wrt comments:**

WSH JScript is not .NET JScript. A 'port' of the above script to .NET looks like:

```
import System;

var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("calc");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
WshShell.AppActivate("calc");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
WshShell.AppActivate("notepad");
```

As you can see, you need to use the sleep feature of the platform (WSH vs .NET).

Comment: Ok this will open a instance of calculator but as soon as it encounters Sleep() my program crashes. What gives?

Comment: Error Message: "[program name].exe" has stopped working checking for solutions" and then "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available"

Comment: @user3764918 - that looks like a problem of "[program name].exe". Can you start it without the .js script? Did you test the script with calc/notepad.exe?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Jscript.JScript.JscriptException: function expected at Microsoft.Jscript.LateBinding.CallCOMObject(IReflect ir, String name, Objectct ob, Binder, Object[] arguments, ParameterModifier[] ..." , Yes I tried it with the windows manually opened already. It specifically hates the Sleep() function because the code runs up to the first call to Sleep()

Comment: @user3764918 - you don't use WSH JScript, but .NET JScript.